# Server to Server authentication in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, jwt, .net-6.0

I have a web api server on lets say, api.app.com which serves data for my app and i have a separate web server on [www.app.com](http://www.app.com) which serves users the pages for the app. I am using a JWT created on the webapi to Authorize the user. The token is created when the client logs in from the login page served on [www.app.com](http://www.app.com) with a username and a password. I want [www.app.com](http://www.app.com) (web server) to send a request to api.app.com (web api) to authenticate the user and then store the token gotten from the web api inside a cookie on the client.

Then i want only api authenticated clients to have access to pages on the web server, while the web server gets data from the web api on the behalf of the client per request.

I have checked everywhere online, without a clear solution to this

Comment: Your question is not clear. First you say you are using JWT against `app`, then you say you want `app` to authenticate user against `api`. So do you have JWT or not? Or you want to use different tokens for `app` and `api`?

Answer (score 0):

Web apis are usually consumers of JWT tokens. Once received they validate the token, and check claims and proceed based on the result. Your environment is a little confusing to me.
It seems your api app is used as an identity server as well as data provider. It is best to separate these concerns.